# Sonata Admin one-to-many relationship with file upload (appendFormFieldElement)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I'm currently facing a challenge with SonataAdminBundle, one-to-many relationships and file uploads. I have an Entity called `Client` and one called `ExchangeFile`. One `Client` can have several `ExchangeFile`s, so we have a one-to-many relationship here. I'm using the [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) for file uploads.

This is the `Client` class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Client extends BaseUser
{    
    // SNIP

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ExchangeFile", mappedBy="client", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    protected $exchangeFiles;

    // SNIP
}
```

and this is the `ExchangeFile` class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="exchange_file")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class ExchangeFile
{
    // SNIP

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize="20M"
     * )
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="exchange_file", fileNameProperty="fileName")
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="file_name", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fileName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client", inversedBy="exchangeFiles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $client;

    // SNIP
}
```

In my `ClientAdmin` class, i added the `exchangeFiles` field the following way:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        // SNIP
        ->with('Files')
            ->add('exchangeFiles', 'sonata_type_collection', array('by_reference' => false), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                ))
        // SNIP
}
```

This allows for inline editing of various exchange files in the Client edit form. And it works well so far: [image: Sonata Admin with one-to-many relationship and file uploads].

**The Problem**

But there's one ceveat: When i hit the green "+" sign once (add a new exchange file form row), **then select a file in my filesystem**, then hit the "+" sign again (a new form row is appended via Ajax), select another file, and then hit "Update" (save the current Client), **then the first file is not persisted**. Only the second file can be found in the database and the file system.

As far as I could find out, this has the following reason: When the green "+" sign is clicked the second time, the current form is post to the web server, including the data currently in the form (Client and all exchange files). A new form is created and the request is bound into the form (this happens in the `AdminHelper` class located in `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin`):

```
public function appendFormFieldElement(AdminInterface $admin, $subject, $elementId)
{
    // retrieve the subject
    $formBuilder = $admin->getFormBuilder();

    $form = $formBuilder->getForm();
    $form->setData($subject);
    $form->bind($admin->getRequest()); // <-- here
    // SNIP
}
```

So the entire form is bound, a form row is appended, the form is sent back to the browser and the entire form is overwritten by the new one. But since file inputs (`<input type="file" />`) cannot be pre-populated for security reasons, the first file is lost. The file is only stored on the filesystem when the entity is persisted (I think `VichUploaderBundle` uses Doctrine's `prePersist` for this), but this does not yet happen when a form field row is appended.

**My first question is**: How can i solve this problem, or which direction should i go? I would like the following use case to work: I want to create a new Client and I know I'll upload three files. I click "New Client", enter the Client data, hit the green "+" button once, select the first file. Then i hit the "+" sign again, and select the second file. Same for the third file. All three files should be persisted.

**Second question**: Why does Sonata Admin post the entire form when I only want to add a single form row in a one-to-many relationship? Is this really necessary? This means that if I have file inputs, all files present in the form are uploaded every time a new form row is added.

Thanks in advance for your help. If you need any details, let me know.

Comment: Seeing as you're already using SonataAdmin, I'd recommend using their [MediaBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle). This isn't just for images - you can configure it to only be used for file uploads if that's all you need.

Comment: Thanks @RobMasters for you fast reply. I think using SonataMediaBundle would add a lot of unnecessary complexity to my application. The MediaBundle would solve the issue by adding a many-to-many relationship between Clients and Exchange Files. But this would mean that Exchange Files might exist with no owner. I'm developing an application that allows for secure exchange of files with critical content, so possibliy having files with no associated Client is something that might lead to problems.

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comment about [SonataMediaBundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle)...

If you do go this route, then you'd want to create a new entity similar to the following:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ClientHasFile
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Client $client
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Story", inversedBy="clientHasFiles")
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @var Media $media
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media")
     */
    private $media;

    // SNIP
}
```

Then, in your Client entity:

```
class Client
{
    // SNIP

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ClientHasFile", mappedBy="client", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $clientHasFiles;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clientHasFiles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // SNIP
}
```

... and your ClientAdmin's configureFormFields:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
{
    $form

    // SNIP

    ->add('clientHasFiles', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
        'required' => false,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'label' => 'Media items'
    ), array(
        'edit' => 'inline',
        'inline' => 'table'
    )
    )
;
}
```

... and last but not least, your ClientHasFileAdmin class:

```
class ClientHasFileAdmin extends Admin
{
    /**
     * @param \Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper $form
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form)
    {
        $form
            ->add('media', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(), array(
                'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'default')
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list)
    {
        $list
            ->add('client')
            ->add('media')
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this makes is possible for a File not to be associated to a Client, right? Anyway, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I looked at it in detail. For that, I don't have to use SonataMediaBundle. I could use any other file class instead of `Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media`. The thing is that this design allows for files which are not associated with any Client, and I really want to avoid that. I think the problem is somewhere else, namely in the form field append mechanism.

Comment: No worries, I didn't realise that was an important part of your business logic. Although since SonataMediaBundle requires for you to create your own Concrete classes, there's probably no reason why you wouldn't be able to add a relation to `Client` from your `Media` entity. It would obviously be a different setup to examples above though.

Comment: That's right, @RobMasters. But I guess that when I implement this as you just said, then I would face the very same problem I'm already facing. The thing is that file inputs in the 'many' part of one-to-many relationships using `sonata_type_collection` simply do not seem to be supported when using Ajax. The problem seems to be in the way how new form rows are appended. It works for any input type that can be pre-populated, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Actually no, I think using SonataMediaBundle would solve this problem, which is why I suggested it. You wouldn't simply be uploading 'files' to the collection, you'd be adding `Media` entities that describe files to the collection - so the uploading would already have taken place before you submit the form.

Comment: That's right. It would allow for files that are not associated to any client, but in this case I would have to solve that problem in a different way. However, I don't understand why the form appending mechanism needs to be so complex and unflexible in Sonat Admin. In the end I think I have to go the direction you suggested, @RobMasters.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out, that it could be possible to solve this problem by remembering the file inputs content before the AJAX call for adding a new row. It's a bit hacky, but it's working as I'm testing it right now.

We are able to override a template for editing - base_edit.html.twig. I've added my javascript to detect the click event on the add button and also a javascript after the row is added.

My sonata_type_collection field is called **galleryImages**.

The full script is here:

```
$(function(){
      handleCollectionType('galleryImages');
});

function handleCollectionType(entityClass){

        let clonedFileInputs = [];
        let isButtonHandled = false;
        let addButton = $('#field_actions_{{ admin.uniqid }}_' + entityClass + ' a.btn-success');

        if(addButton.length > 0){
            $('#field_actions_{{ admin.uniqid }}_' + entityClass + ' a.btn-success')[0].onclick = null;
            $('#field_actions_{{ admin.uniqid }}_' + entityClass + ' a.btn-success').off('click').on('click', function(e){

                if(!isButtonHandled){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    clonedFileInputs = cloneFileInputs(entityClass);

                    isButtonHandled = true;

                    return window['start_field_retrieve_{{ admin.uniqid }}_'+entityClass]($('#field_actions_{{ admin.uniqid }}_' + entityClass + ' a.btn-success')[0]);
                }
            });

            $(document).on('sonata.add_element', '#field_container_{{ admin.uniqid }}_' + entityClass, function() {
                refillFileInputs(clonedFileInputs);

                isButtonHandled = false;
                clonedFileInputs = [];

                handleCollectionType(entityClass);
            });
        }


}

function cloneFileInputs(entityClass){
        let clonedFileInputs = [];
        let originalFileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"][id^="{{ admin.uniqid }}_' + entityClass + '"]');

        for(let i = 0; i < originalFileInputs.length; i++){
            clonedFileInputs.push(originalFileInputs[i].cloneNode(true));
        }

        return clonedFileInputs;
}

function refillFileInputs(clonedFileInputs){
        for(let i = 0; i < clonedFileInputs.length; i++){
            let originalFileInput = document.getElementById(clonedFileInputs[i].id);
            originalFileInput.replaceWith(clonedFileInputs[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different approaches and workaround and in the end I found out  that the best solution in the one described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154867/4249725

You just have to hide all the unnecessary list/delete buttons around the file selection if they are not needed.

In all other cases with file selection directly inside the form you will face some other problems sooner or later - with form validation, form preview etc. In all these case input fields will be cleared.

So using  media bundle and sonata_type_model_list is probably the safest option despite quite a lot of overhead.

I'm posting it in case someone is searching for the solution the way I was searching.

I've found also some java-script workaround for this exact problem. It worked basically changing names of file inputs when you hit "+" button and then reverting it back.

Still in this case you are still left with the problem of re-displaying the form if some validation fails etc. so I definitely suggest media bundle approach.