# symfony2 many-to-many sonata admin model_list

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am using latest Symfony2 and Sonata Admin to maintain my site and this is my problem:

I have two entities: Shop and Discount. One shop can have many discounts and one discount can be assigned to many shops. Therefore it should be **Many to Many** relation.

I would like to use sonatata`s type_model_list in ShopAdmin so I can choose from a popup window these discounts and select multiple. Is this possible?

This is part of my Shop Entity:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;   
 ...
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ShoppingFever\ShoppingFeverBundle\Entity\Discount", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="discountId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $discountId;
```

And this is the relative ShopAdmin of function configureFormFields:

```
$formMapper
        ->add('shopName',null, array('label' => 'Název obchodu'))
        ->add('brandName',null, array('label' => 'Název brandu'))
        ->add('discountId', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
            'btn_add'       => 'Add discount',      //Specify a custom label
            'btn_list'      => 'button.list',     //which will be translated
            'btn_delete'    => false,             //or hide the button.
            'btn_catalogue' => 'SonataNewsBundle' //Custom translation domain for buttons
        ), array(
            'placeholder' => 'Nothing selected',
            'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'by_reference' => false
        ))
        ->add('street',null, array('label' => 'Ulice'))
        ->add('city',null, array('label' => 'Město'))
        ->add('zip',null, array('label' => 'PSČ'))
        ->add('gps',null, array('label' => 'GPS'))
        ->add('openingHours','textarea', array('label' => 'Otevírací doba'))
        ->add('eventId',null, array('required'=>false,'label' => 'Event'));
```

If I had **One To Many** relation (one discount to any shop), the admin works. Symfony generated the reference table for discount and shop ids to work for **many to many**.

This is the **One To Many** output and I would like this to work for Many To Many, so where now it says Swarovski, there would be several discounts.

[image: This outputs the **One To Many**]

Is it possible to do it with many to many as well?

Comment: To achieve the desired output you have to create entity for you junction table which behaves as intermediate entity and holds relation for both shop and discount entity , to have a better idea have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712459/handling-multiple-file-uploads-in-sonata-admin-bundle/25154867#25154867 i have implemented it for other purpose but you can pick a logic from there

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `sonata_type_model_list` with a **many-to-many** relation.
What you can do is to use `sonata_type_model` instead and set the option `multiple` to `true`:

```
->add('discountId', 'sonata_type_model', array(
    'multiple' => true,
    // other options
))
```

For the current version of **SonataAdminBundle** (as of today 2019-02-18 it is 3.x) the example should look like:

```
// import ModelType
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\Type\ModelType;

// code example
->add('discountId', ModelType::class, [
    'multiple' => true,
    // other options
])
```

This will create a dropdown list to select multiple related objects and **Add new** button (or **Add discount** if you set that trough `btn_add`) to create a new related object.