# sonata sonata_type_collection display table

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have two entities: "Event" and "EventImage". One event can have multiple images.

This is the relationship defined on the Event table:

```
**
* Event
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\EventRepository")
*/

class Event
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EventImage", mappedBy="event")
     */
    protected $eventImages;

}
```

and this is the relationship defined on the EventImage table:

```
/**
 * EventImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\EventImageRepository")
 */
class EventImage
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="eventImages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $event;
}
```

and in my "configureFormFields" in EventAdmin

```
$formMapper
    ->add('eventImages', 'sonata_type_collection',array(), array(
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'standard',
                        'sortable'  => 'listOrder'
                ))
```

and in my "" in EventImageAdmin

```
$formMapper
    ->add('id')
    ->add('imagePath', 'text')
->end()
;
```

Now I saw some example around where you get a nice formatted table, with each pulled record in a row, with a checkbox to delete the row and also the dragging option, and also the "add a new row" button to link a new element(or add a new one)

But all i got is a cascade list of associated eventImage records, not formatted in a table, with no "add a new row" option.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In your `EventImageAdmin` there is no need of `id` field also use `sonata_type_model_list` for `imagePath`

```
  $formMapper
        ->add('imagePath', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => false));
```

In your `EventAdmin` define `admin_code` service id of `EventImageAdmin` in fourth parameter of `$formMapper`'s `add()` function

```
$formMapper
    ->add( 'eventImages', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
            'cascade_validation' => false,
            'type_options'       => array( 'delete' => false ),
        ), array(

            'edit'            => 'inline',
            'inline'          => 'table',
            'sortable'        => 'position',
            'link_parameters' => array( 'context' => 'define context from which you want to select media or else just add default' ),
            'admin_code'      => 'sonata.admin.your_service_id_here'
            /*here provide service name for junction admin */
        )
    );
```

For more see my another answer regarding [**`Handling multiple file uploads in Sonata Admin Bundle`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25154867/853360)

Answer (score 1):

You missed some options. Try this :

```
  ->add('eventImages', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'by_reference' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'type_options' => array('delete' => true),
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'btn_add' => 'Add new EventImages',
                "required" => false ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table'
            ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that didn't work. I still get the same cascade of records with no option for adding....